# Create pivot table on large pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, recommendation-engine

I am trying to use the pd.pivot_table() method to create a user-item matrix by pivoting the user-item activity data for my recommendation engine development. However, the dataframe is so large that I got complain like this:

```
Unstacked DataFrame is too big, causing int32 overflow
```

Any suggestions on solving this problem? Thanks!

Comment: have you tried read your csv using chunksize?

Comment: @Terry I didn't. I think I figured out a way. Instead of directly using pd.pivot_table, I did something like df.groupby([col_user,col_item])[col_frequency].sum() first to calculate the frequency of each user-item pairs, then generated indices for unique values of user and item filed, and finally generated user-item csr_matrix based on the indices and frequency value. It is much faster than the pd.pivot_table route.

Comment: I have same problem. Can i see your code?